# postgresql aggregate function inside loop

Tags: postgresql, loops, for-loop, aggregate-functions

i am trying create this function, but i receive this error:
ERROR:  "max" is not a known variable

but, if i use one of aggregate functions works fine, but not both functions in same time

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GerarTeste"()
  RETURNS BOOL  AS 
    $BODY$
    DECLARE     
            inicio date;
            fim date;
            rResult record;     
    BEGIN
        FOR rResult IN 
            SELECT DISTINCT  lote 
            FROM  fatura 
            ORDER BY lote
        LOOP
            SELECT 
                 MIN(fatura.inicio) INTO inicio ,MAX(fatura.inicio) into fim
            FROM fatura
            WHERE lote = rResult.lote;      

            RAISE NOTICE '%',inicio;

        END LOOP;
        RETURN true;
    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the function. It is an extremely complicated and expensive way to write `return true;`

Comment: And there is also no need for a loop. You can simply do `select .. where lote in (select lote from fatura)` and get rid of the slow loop

Comment: is just an example....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple columns, you still only have a single `into`

```
        SELECT MIN(fatura.inicio), MAX(fatura.inicio) 
            into inicio, fim --<< here
        FROM fatura
        WHERE lote = rResult.lote;
```